# Stream or file is not closing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file, stream

I have he following code

```
    HttpPostedFileBase files = Request.Files[0];
    Stream fileStream = files.InputStream;

    using (Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(originalImage))
    {
        StreamUtil.CopyStream(fileStream, file);
        file.Close();
        fileStream.close();
        fileStream.dispose();
    }

    // here is CopyStream method

    public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[8*1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
```

When i try to write the same file twice i get

```
The process cannot access the file \u0027D:FILENAME because it is being used by another process
```

How can i close this ?so once the request the writing is done, it will be closed?

Comment: What is `fileStream`? Where does it come from?

Comment: updated the code, it s coming from request.

Comment: Does this happen _every_ time you try to write to the same file again? Did you try using [filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) to see what process is locking the file?

Comment: yes it happens everytime i upload the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to write it as a comment but it is not clear so:

Try doing something like this:

```
MemoryStream fileStream = new MemoryStream();

fileStream.WriteByte(04);

using (Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(originalImage))
{
    CopyStream(fileStream, file);
}

using (Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(originalImage))
{
    CopyStream(fileStream, file);
}
```

Do you get the same error on the second using line?

Comment: I am trying to check if you get the same message if you open the file right after you close it (because i think the file is not locked from your posted code, but from somewhere else).
If you will try to open it twice and you won't get the message you can be sure that the file is locked from somewhere else.

Comment: that s really not a valid solution what i did was to add date time ticks to file name so it wont be same file again

Comment: I said i wanted to write it as a comment and not as an answer... but from your answer i guess i know what happend!
i think you had the same code running from multiple threads **using the same file name** and then if two threads were running on the same time then the first one would succeed opening the file and the second will get the error message. am i right?

Comment: That means that you get exception on the second Stream file = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(originalImage) call???

Comment: i didnt try. my workaround was prepend datetime to the beginning of the file, so it creates a new file everytime, user uploads.